# How to start all print by a tab in Python

Tags: javascript, python, command-line

I have a script (in Python), that is called by another script (in JavaScript). And to have better readability of the log in my command line, I'd like that all the prints of the subscript (in Python) start with a tabulation. Is there a way to do that with one command, or should I put manually a `\t` at the beginning of all my print?

I wanted to add the tab in the calling script, but when there are several prints in a row, only the first one gets the tab.

PS: if it can help, the calling of the Python script:

```js
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
const pythonProcess = spawn('python3', ["../pythonscript.py"]);
pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {          
  buff = Buffer.from(data.toString().trim(), "utf-8");

  console.log('Python answer = ' + buff.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is clearly a post-processing step to be done in Javascript.

Unless you have complete control over your script, there is lots of ways how things might be printed without tab:

- Strings containing `\n`
- automatic log/warning messages from libraries
- Forgetting the prefix somewhere
- etc.

Just use `buff.toString().split("\n").join("\n\t")` in JS.

Comment: On second thought, ``.replace("\n", "\n\t")`` is even simpler :-)

Comment: Indeed! I didn't though about just modifying the string itself. My mind was blocked to add automatically the print at the beginning of the print.